# TypeError: string indices must be integers for JSON

Tags: python, json

I am writing a program in Python to prompt for a URL, read the JSON data from that URL using urllib and then parse and extract the comment counts from the JSON data, compute the sum of the numbers in the file and enter the sum below. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import json

total = 0
url = open("comments_42.json")
print 'Retrieving', url
#uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = url.read()
print 'Retrieved',len(data),'characters'
#print data

info = json.loads(data)
print info
print 'User count:', len(info)


for item in info:
    print item['count']
    total = total + item['count']

print total
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers" for "print item['count']
```

Why do they have to be integers? My instructor on Coursera did a similar thing. Any advice?

The JSON file has this structure:

```
{
  comments: [
    {
      name: "Matthias"
      count: 97
    },
    {
      name: "Geomer"
      count: 97
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Similar is not the same. It was most likely a dictionary, where the key can be of any (hashable) type.

Comment: It seems `item` is a `string` and not a `dict`.

Comment: all things remaining equal, not a bad idea to see if your json is indeed valid json.  http://jsonlint.com/ says it ain't.

Comment: It looks very similar to [this (valid) dataset](http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json) made by a [Dr. Charles Severance](http://www.dr-chuck.com/). OP, if you fix the syntax errors my answer should work

Answer (score 0):

The error `"TypeError: string indices must be integers" for "print item['count']"` says that `item` is a string; in this case it's a dictionary key.

I haven't seen your JSON but if your "comments_42.json" is [this dataset](http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.json), try the code below:

```
total = 0
for item in info["comments"]:
    print item['count']
    total += item["count"]
```

I found it [here](http://pastebin.com/raw/fT52jU9B) (maybe someone solved this  challenge or whatever it is and uploaded the solution)

Comment: Okay, so I tried your code and it's going "ImportError: no module named requests."

Comment: @abadila123 `requests` is only needed to fetch the dataset online. You seem to have it on your computer so you can remove that. Check my updated answer. Btw. we could solve this in a minute if you posted the json or some of it in your question

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that item is a string, meaning your JSON structure isn't like the one you used in your course.  For example

```
info = ['the', 'items', 'inside', 'this', 'list', 'are', 'strings']

for item in info:
    # Items here are strings (the, information, etc)
    print(items) # this will print each word in the list




info = {'sentence': 'the', 'items', 'inside', 'this', 'list', 'are', 'strings'}

for items in info:
    # This is a dictionary, which can be addressed by the key name
    print(items['sentence'])  # this is what you're expecting, because 'sentence' is a dictionary key.
```

If you add your JSON response to the original question, we can help you understand how to access the items you want.